# Делегат с кастомным UINavigationController равен nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Использую фреймворк typhoon для DI, по ходу тестирования нашел непонятную проблему, когда я устанавливаю делегат в UIViewController то все хорошо, он не nil, но к примеру в UITabBarController уже установить не получается, так же не получается его установить в кастомный навигейшнконтроллер, делегат тоже nil. Вот собственно сам assemby. в самом первом методе устанавливается делегат - output.

```
    @implementation SlideMenuAssembly

- (SlideNavigationController*)viewControllerSlideModule
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[SlideNavigationController class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
                              [definition injectProperty:@selector(output)
                                                    with:[self presenterSlideModule]];
                          }];
}

- (SlideMenuPresenter *)presenterSlideModule
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[SlideMenuPresenter class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

                              [definition injectProperty:@selector(view)
                                                    with:[self viewControllerSlideModule]];

                              [definition injectProperty:@selector(interactor)
                                                    with:[self interactorSlideModule]];

                              [definition injectProperty:@selector(router)
                                                    with:[self routerSlideModule]];

                          }];
}

- (SlideMenuRouter *)routerSlideModule
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[SlideMenuRouter class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition injectProperty:@selector(view)
                              with:[self viewControllerSlideModule]];

        [definition injectProperty:@selector(presenter)
                              with:[self presenterSlideModule]];

    }];
}

- (SlideMenuInteractor *)interactorSlideModule
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[SlideMenuInteractor class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition injectProperty:@selector(output)
                              with:[self presenterSlideModule]];

    }];
}

@end
```

И вот именно в SlideNavigationController, c такой иньекцией output будет nil.
Вот код интерфейса контроллера

```
@interface SlideNavigationController : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, SlideMenuViewInput>

extern NSString * const SlideNavigationControllerDidOpen;
extern NSString  *const SlideNavigationControllerDidClose;
extern NSString  *const SlideNavigationControllerDidReveal;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SlideMenuViewOutput> output;
@end
```

Это код презентера:

```
@interface SlideMenuPresenter : NSObject <SlideMenuInteractorOutput, SlideMenuModuleInput, SlideMenuViewOutput>

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <SlideMenuViewInput> view;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <SlideMenuInteractorInput> interactor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <SlideMenuRouterInput> router;

- (void)configureModule;

@end
```

интересно то, что делегат нормально устанавливается если унаследовать не от UINavigationController, а от UIViewController.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под делегатом? В вашем коде нигде не устанавливается поле "delegate".

Comment: @Anastasia, делегат это output у SlideMenuController , сейчас уточню.

Comment: Я не работала с typhoon, и не знаю что там внутри происходит, но если ради эксперимента в `@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SlideMenuViewOutput> output;` поменять `weak` на `strong`?

Comment: @Anastasia нет, это тоже не срабатывает, что насчет UINavigationController, я уже решил проблему, хоть и все равно не понял почему до этого не работало, а что касается UITabBarController, то для меня он останется пока что загадкой , почему там output не инжектится, а все остальные контроллеры нормально инжектят output.

Comment: а можно какой то минимальный пример этого кейса в действии, это надо дебажить, а самому писать целое приложение не хочется